# Computing singular value decomposition via Matlab script

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 10&20\\ -3 & 4  \end{pmatrix}$.

I want to compute the svd decomposition $A=USV'$ via matlab, but I do not want to use the function `svd`.

First of all, I have to compute the vector $U$ and $V$, so:

`A=[10 20;-3 4]; 
 [U,D]=eig(A*A');
 [V,D]=eig(A'*A);`

The problem is that my matrix $D$ has the property  $D(1,1)<D(2,2)$. In order to find my matrix $S$ I have to type:

`S=sqrt(diag([D(2,2) D(1,1)]))`

But, since I reverted the order of the elements from the diagonal matrix, I also have to swap the columns of $U$ and $V$ in order to maintain the correspondence beetween the eigevectors and the eigenvalues previously computed:

`V(:,[1 2])=V(:,[2 1]);
U(:,[1 2])=U(:,[2 1]);`

And the result is:

`U*S*V'`

But the result (shown below) its not equal to $A$!

$\begin{pmatrix} -10&-20\\ +3 & -4  \end{pmatrix}$.

**EDIT**:
Computing the SVD decomposition through the matlab function `svd`

`[U1,S1,V1]=svd(A)`

we can note some differences:

From my computation 
$U = \begin{pmatrix} -0.9946 & 0.1036
\\ -0.1036  & -0.9946  \end{pmatrix}$ and from matlab: $U1 = \begin{pmatrix} -0.9946 & -0.1036
\\ -0.1036  & 0.9946  \end{pmatrix}$ we see that the difference its in the second eigenvector of $AA'$ since they are multiples of $-1$ to each other.

A similar difference happens beetween $V$ and $V1$, in this case, however, the **first** eigenvector of $A'A$ are multiple of $-1$ to each other.

I thought that $U$ and $V$ should be just an orthogonal matrix whose columns are constitued by, respectively, eigenvectors of $AA'$ and $A'A$. And the matrices $U$ and $V$ that I computed satisfies these conditions, so why am I having this wrong result?

Sorry for the long post..